# Sub that copies/pastes from defined names on different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Problem:

I have two (dynamic) lists that are named `MarketsEquities` and `MarketsBonds` and are found on worksheets `SummaryEquities` and `SummaryBonds`, respectively.

I then have a worksheet named `PnL` where I want to create a list of the markets listed in the previous worksheets. These Markets should all be listed in column C and a space should be provided between the end of the equities list and the start of the bond list, wherein I shall write in column B `Bonds`.

This is what I've got thus far:

```
Sub InsertEquitiesBonds()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("PnL")
    ws.Activate
    Set Range("B3").Value = "Equities"
    Set r1 = Worksheets("SummaryEquities").Range("MarketsEquities")
    r1.Copy Range("C4")

    'I want to then insert "Bonds" in Column B at the end of the listing of equities and then list all bonds in column C below that. 

    Set r2 = Worksheets("SummaryBonds").Range("MarketsBonds")
End Sub
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you look in the Name Manager, is the Scope of your Named Ranges the Worksheet, or the Workbook?  If "Workbook", then you can just use `ThisWorkbook.Range("MarketsEquities")` instead of needing to specify the worksheet name (which is far too easy for users to change...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I recommend to specify a worksheet for **every** `Range()` or `Cells()` statement like `ws.Range("C4")` otherwise Excel guesses which worksheet you mean.
2. You can determine the last used cell in a column with

   ```
   ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp) 'last used cell in column B
   ```

   and you can use `.Offset(row, column)` to move rows/columns relatively from that cell.

So I suggest the following:

```
Public Sub InsertEquitiesBonds()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("PnL")

    ws.Range("B3").Value = "Equities"
    Worksheets("SummaryEquities").Range("MarketsEquities").Copy ws.Range("C4")


    Dim LastUsedCell As Range
    Set LastUsedCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp) 'last used cell in column B

    LastUsedCell.Offset(2, 0).Value = "Bonds" 'move 2 cells down and write Bonds
    Worksheets("SummaryBonds").Range("MarketsBonds").Copy LastUsedCell.Offset(3, 1) 'copy MarketsBonds 3 cells down and one cell right of the last used cell
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help. i have one more question, however. Is it possible to let the macro immediately execute once I fill the lists on the respective worksheets SummaryEquities and SummaryBonds, rather than having to click on run macro or creating an equivalent keyboard shortcut

Comment: Since this is actually possible to do I cannot recommend to do it, because this would do the copy action after *every* cell change and your Excel will get unresponsively slow by doing so. I recommend to use a button instead.

Comment: Alternatively you can use the `Worksheet_Activate()` event of your `PnL` and ask the user if he want's to update the data. So everytime the user clicks on `PnL` tab it runs.